# address changes when i assign to a pointer a pointer from a derived class in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm a brand new in C++ and I'm experimenting with Polymorphism. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base1
{
protected:
    int b1;

public:
    int m() { return 1; }
};

class Base2
{
protected:
    int b2;

public:
    int n() { return 2; }
};

class Der : public Base1, public Base2
{
protected:
    int d1;

public:
    int m() { return 11; }
    int n() { return 21; }
};

int main()
{
    Der *ptr = new Der();
    Base1 *b1 = ptr;
    Base2 *b2 = ptr;

    std::cout << "d: " << ptr << ", m: " << ptr->m() << ", n: " << ptr->n() << "\n";
    std::cout << "b1: " << b1 << ", m: " << b1->m() << "\n";
    std::cout << "b2: " << b2 << ", n: " << b2->n() << "\n";

    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

When i run this code the interesting thing is that b2 is shifted by 4 bytes, here my output:

```
d: 0x564eab6cbeb0, m: 11, n: 21
b1: 0x564eab6cbeb0, m: 1
b2: 0x564eab6cbeb4, n: 2
```

Why this happens only with b2? I guess it's related on how things are stored in memory because if I remove the int field in b1 b2 is not affected. Is there a way to see easily stack and heap? I would like to see what happens. (I'm using Virtual Studio Code)

Comment: you forgot add virtual to your function-members, so you are not using polymorphism, you are shadowing methods

Comment: no I have not, i'm experimenting with various way to achieve some kind of polymorphism in C++ this one, virtual that fake what happens in Java by default using virtual tables and the CRTP method. Anyway I have the shift even though i use virtual methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample of OP (simplified a bit)

```
struct Base1 {
  int b1;
};

struct Base2 {
  int b2;
};

struct Der: Base1, Base2 { };
```

may result in the following memory layout:

```
// start of Der
// start of Base1
0000: Base1::b1 // type int
// start of Base2
0004: Base2::b2 // type int
```

So, when `struct Der` is instanced part of its contents is an instance of `struct Base2` but it doesn't start at the same address of the `Der` instance.

With

```
Der *ptr = new Der();
```

the initialization

```
Base2 *b2 = ptr;
```

doesn't result in a plain copy of the address in `ptr` to `b2`. There is also an implicit conversion from `Der*` to `Base2*` involved. The compiler is aware of the relation of classes `Der` and `Base2`. Hence, the conversion results in a silent addition of the offset of `Base2` in `Der`.

To show this in action, I made a small demo. (I'm not sure how convincing it is.):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base1 {
  int b1 = 1;
};

struct Base2 {
  int b2 = 2;
};

struct Der: Base1, Base2 { };

int main()
{
  Der *ptr = new Der;
  Base2 *b2;
  std::cout << "ptr:" << ptr << ", ptr1->b2: " << ptr->b2 << '\n';
  b2 = ptr;
  std::cout << "b2: " << b2 << ", b2->b2: " << b2->b2 << '\n';
}
```

Compiled with gcc 4.1.2, you can find the following code where the actual assignment happens:

```
        mov     %rax, QWORD PTR [%rbp-24] # %rbp-24 <- storage of ptr on stack
        add     %rax, 4
        mov     QWORD PTR [%rbp-32], %rax # %rbp-32 <- storage of b2 on stack
```

[**Live Demo on CompilerExplorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/VhPDpD)

**Note:**

Compiling with most modern compiler version will emit a similar `add` command but also a lot of other stuff which is not as easy to decipher (by eyes) than the generated code of the older version. Hence, I've chosen the oldest `gcc` I could find.

Comment: yes it was exactly what i was looking for, it perfectly make sense and i do really appreciate the details on what assembler code is generated by those instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's related on how things are stored in memory.

Class `Der` includes `Base1` and `Base2` as a subobject.

Look this [derived_class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class).

Comment: I know that derived objects include base objects but I'm focusing on pointers, the problem is why b1 has the same address of ptr while b2 has not even though b1 = ptr and b2 = ptr. I would like to be sure of why this happens and a more detailed explanation on how these variables are stored in memory.

Comment: @GJCode It's not that the address in `ptr` is simply copied to `b2`. It also includes an implicit (speak "silent") conversion from `Der*` to `Base2*`. To make `b2` a proper pointer to `Base2` (while assigning `ptr`) the compiler is aware of the offset of `Base2` in `Der` and adds the offset in the assignment of `b2`.

Comment: so what you are saying is the following: i have a der obj that in memory looks like this: [base1(base1_fields),base2(base2_fields),der(der_fields)] so when i do b2 = ptr the compiler says ok the lval is of type Base2, Der contains a Base2 obj so lets point to it instead doing ptr + base1. Is this correct? So we are assuming continous allocation and in the order that i specify when i do Der: public Base1, public Base2.

Comment: @GJCode In short: Yes. I added an answer to explain it a bit longer. ;-)